# Incident duration (select from mysql)

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

In the database MySQL, there is a table with information about the changing status of the object with the "problem" or "unknown" to "ok":

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `eventid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `source` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `object` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `objectid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `clock` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `acknowledged` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ns` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value_changed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventid`),
  KEY `events_1` (`object`,`objectid`,`eventid`),
  KEY `events_2` (`clock`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


eventid | objectid | clock | value
77843   13619   1341588185  0
77859   13619   1341589085  2
77889   13619   1341590585  0
82174   13619   1341843065  2
82193   13619   1341843785  1
82197   13619   1341843965  0
```

where, value 0 - ok 1 - problem, 2 - unknown, and the clock - time (format unixtime).

There is a query that counts the duration of the event for the specified time:

```
select a.eventid,a.objectid,a.`interval` from (
select
@prev_clock,
@prev_value,
l.*,
if(l.value='0' && @prev_value!='0' &&
@prev_objectid=l.objectid,TIMEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.clock),FROM_UNIXTIME(@prev_clock)),null) 'interval',
(@prev_clock:=l.clock),(@prev_value:=l.value),(@prev_objectid:=l.objectid)
from events l,(select @vclock:=0,@prev_value:='',@prev_objectid:=0) b1
where l.clock>=1341588185 and objectid=13619
order by l.objectid,l.eventid
) a where a.value='0';
```

Here is the result:

```
eventid objectid    interval
77843   13619   
77889   13619   00:25:00
82197   13619   00:03:00
```

Help, correct query / expression if, according to the following conditions:

1) The status can change from 0 to 1, then 2, then back to 1 (and so many times) .... and much later to 0 (for example, the duration of the event 82 197 = 1341843965-1341843065 = 900 seconds and not 180).

2) in the "interval" of cells, there should be no empty values.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like:

```
SELECT e.eventid AS eventid_OK, errEvent.eventid AS eventid_ERROR, e.objectid, TIMEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(e.clock),FROM_UNIXTIME(errEvent.clock)) 
FROM events AS e
INNER JOIN events AS errEvent 
    ON errEvent.clock = (SELECT MIN(err.clock) 
                         FROM events AS err 
                         WHERE err.objectid = e.objectid 
                         AND err.clock > (SELECT MAX(prev.clock) 
                                          FROM events AS prev 
                                          WHERE prev.objectid = e.objectid 
                                          AND prev.clock < e.clock 
                                          AND prev.value = 0) 
                         AND err.value IN (1,2)) 

WHERE e.value = 0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20354/3

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When I try to execute the code gives an error: MySQL Database Error: Unknown column 'errEvent' in 'field list' Line 1 Position 0

Comment: Thank you. I can not check. In the table more than 80,000 rows and the query works very long. I need something "faster". (

Comment: Do an explain and check your indexes.